# Fullscreen UICollectionView: how to add spacing between Fullscreen cells (or sections) while scrolling

Tags: xcode, ios7, uicollectionview, image-gallery, uicollectionviewlayout

How do I using the `UICollectionView` build a paged image gallery with spacing between items while scrolling, but items should be fullscreen?

if I set

```
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0
```

this spacing will be forever and paging will be broken

Answer (score 1):

Add inter-item or inter-line spacing, as you have in your post. Then make the collection view stick out past the bounds of the screen by the same amount as the spacing. So, if you add 10 pt between items, then the collection view should stick out 5 pt on each side (I think; I might be off by a factor of 2).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I had to do in iOS 9, Swift:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    //UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width - 6, self.collectionView.bounds.size.height)
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 6
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 3, 0, 3)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 6
}
```

So, as the code above shows, every **UICollectionViewCell** has **6px** between each other when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

For line spacing 10 in viewDidLoad set collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: -5, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width + 10, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height) and then in UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return view.bounds.size
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
}
```

It's worked for me. Hope it helps somebody